# How to prevent DbSet Results view return all rows in debug

Tags: entity-framework

When a developer click on the results view in debug, it will return all rows of the table.  How to prevent because it may be a very large table?

Thanks
Wilson

Comment: Write your own debug viewer. Depends on VS version how to do this. Google will tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.   Do you think is there a way to add the searching criteria to the base query and change the parameter like Dataset?

Comment: Well, you can do anything if you write your own debug viewer. I don't really understand what you mean. Maybe give it a shot and come back with a more concrete question?

Comment: The default sql statement should be select column1, column 2 ... from table1.  If it is select

Comment: The default sql statement should be :

select column1, column 2 ... from table1  

If it is:

select column1, column 2 ... from table1 where column1 = 'somthing'

Then the number of result will be reasonable even someone click on mistake.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't click on "results view"
2. Run against a test database with a small amount of data
3. Use a QuickWatch such as `context.Clients.Take(20)` (where `Clients` is the name of the `DbSet` you wish to view a subset of data on).
4. Declare a local variable with a filter to see a specific subset of data, `var view1 = context.Clients.Where( x => x.id == 1)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think developers know how to minimize the result set.  It should be a mistake so I wonder is there a way like DataSet searching criteria parameters.